# Retrieving User ID claim from ADFS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, azure, adfs, adfs3.0

I have an ASP.NET application that is currently authenticating against an Azure Active Directory.  When the user authenticates, one of the Claims returned to my application is ObjectIdentifier and I am using this GUID to link a local 'User' record in SQL Server to this AD User.

The code I'm using is this:

```
var uri = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier";
var memberId = Guid.Parse(incomingPrincipal.FindFirst(uri).Value);
```

There is now a requirement to move this application On Premises and authenticate against a local ADFS server.

I've got the application successfully authenticating against the local ADFS server, but the above objectidentifier claim is not present in the Claims and I can't see in ADFS where to add the objectidentifier claim:

[image]

I've got no problem with changing the code above to use a different claim, but some guidance as to which claim would be a unique ID for the user would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AD and AAD are not the same thing and were never designed to be equivalent.

That AAD attribute is not present in AD. The nearest equivalent is objectGuid.

In terms of selecting the attribute, that dropdown is actually editable : refer [ADFS : Selecting claim that's not in the default drop down](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2011/09/adfs-selecting-claim-thats-not-in.html) .